# Powershell: Advanced file age searching

Tags: powershell, csv, automation

This is my first post within Stackoverflow, I have for many years just read many fantastic questions, answers and other various posts. I have learned a lot a lot from this fantastic community. I hope now that I have taken the brave step to really sink my teeth into powershell and join this community that I may be able to contribute in someway!

So I have started working on a project which at it's basic core level - list all files that are older than 7 years so they can then review and delete where possible.

I have however broken the whole entire script up into several stages. I am currently stuck at a step in stage 2.

I have been stuck for about 2 days on what to many of you powershell genius's out there may only take 10mins to figure out!

I must apologise for my stupidity and lack of knowledge, my experience with powershell scripting is limited to literally 5 working days, I am currently diving in and learning with books, but I also have a job to do so don't get to learn the easy way!

My script essentially has 3 steps;

1. Runs a Get-ACL of top Level DATA folders to create a listing of all Groups that have permissions on particular folder. I want to then either export this data or simply hold it for the next step.
2. Filter this gathered information based off a CSV which contains a Column labelled Role (Role will contain a group that the Folder Manager is exclusively in), and check the inherent member of this exlcusive group (maybe this last bit needs to be another step as well?)
3. Stores or Exports this list of exclusive members with their relevant folder to then later use as a variable for to send an email with a list of files that need to be deleted.

With the script below I am essentially stuck on Step 2 and how to create a filter from the CSV (or stored variables?) and apply it to the GET-ACL foreach loop. I may be going about this the whole wrong way using regex, and to be honest most of this is copy and paste and reading around the internet where people have done similar tasks. SO again I apologise if this is just a dumb way to go about it from the start!

I want to thank everyone in advance for all help, opinions and advice, I will listen to it all and I will try and take on-board as much as my brain can handle - I promise!

```
#$RoleList = import-csv "C:\DATA\scripts\GB_CMS\CSV\datafolders_rolelist.csv"
#foreach ($Manager in $RoleList) {
#$FolderManager = $RoleList.Role

$FolderManagers = Import-Csv C:\DATA\scripts\GB_CMS\CSV\datafolders_rolelist.csv | foreach {
  New-Object PSObject -prop @{
    Folder = $_.Folder;
    Manager = $_.'Folder Manager';
    Role = $_.Role


  }
}

$Role = $FolderManagers.Role
$Role


gci "c:\DATA" | Where {$_.PSIsContainer} | get-acl |
 ForEach $_.Name {
 [regex]$regex="\w:\\\S+"
 $path=$regex.match($_.Path).Value
 $_ | select -expand access |

 $

 where {$_.identityreference -like "$Role"} |
 Select @{Name="Path";Expression={$Path}},IdentityReference
 }
```

Thanks,
Daniel.

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a guess at what you want here. e.g. if you have folders

```
C:\Data\Accounts
C:\Data\Marketing
C:\Data\Sales
```

You might have permissions

```
C:\Data\Accounts    {'FolderManagers-Accounts', 'Accounts', 'Directors'}
C:\Data\Marketing   {'FolderManagers-Marketing', 'Marketing', 'Sales'}
C:\Data\Sales       {'FolderManagers-Sales', 'Sales', 'Directors'}
```

and your CSV is

```
Name,  Role,                     Email
Alice, FolderManagers-Accounts,  alice@example.com
Bob,   FolderManagers-Marketing, bob@example.com
```

And there will be a clear mapping of one (1) row in the CSV to one of the groups in the ACLs.

And you want, from your script:

```
Identify who to email about "C:\Data\Accounts"
```

How close am I?

```
# Import the managers. This will turn the CSV into an array of objects
# no need to do that explicitly
$FolderManagers = Import-Csv C:\DATA\scripts\GB_CMS\CSV\datafolders_rolelist.csv

# This will be a hashtable pairing up folder names with people
# e.g. 'C:\DATA\Accounts' -> Alice
$FolderMap = @{}

# Run through all the folders
GetChildItem -Path "C:\Data" -Directory | ForEach-Object {

    # Run through the group/user ACL entries on the folder
    foreach ($group in (Get-Acl $_.FullName).Access.IdentityReference)
    {
        # Look for a matching row in the CSV
        $CsvRow = $FolderManagers | Where-Object {$_.Role -match $group}

        if (-not $CsvRow)
        {
            Write-Error "No manager found for folder $_"
        }
        else
        {
            # Add to the map
            # $_ converts to folder path, C:\DATA\Accounts
            # $CsvRow is the person, @{Name=Alice, Role=..., Email=...}
            $FolderMap[$_.FullName] = $CsvRow
        }

    }
}
```

Then it (the FolderMap) will be

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                    
----                           -----                                                                                                                                    
C:\Data\Accounts               {Name='Alice';Role=...
C:\Data\Marketing              {Name='Bob';Role=...
```

you can query it with

```
$person = $FolderMap["c:\data\Accounts"]
$person.email
```

and if you really want to export it, maybe

```
$FolderMap | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content foldermanagers.json
```

Nb. I wrote most of this off the top of my head, and it probably won't just run. And that's a problem with big, not very specific questions on StackOverflow.

---

**Auto-generated PS help links from my codeblock** (if available):

- [`Import-Csv`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113341) (in module `Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility`)
- [`ForEach-Object`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113300)
- [`Get-Acl`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113305) (in module `Microsoft.PowerShell.Security`)
- [`Where-Object`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113423)
- [`Write-Error`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113425) (in module `Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility`)

Comment: Hi,

Thanks so much for the response and forgive me for the delay in responding.

I have tested this and as you said, I had issues running it initially. I get the issue with this line;

    # Run through the group/user ACL entries on the folder
    foreach ($group in (Get-Acl $_).Access.IdentityReference)

It is producing this error:

Get-Acl : Cannot find path 'Folder1' because it does not exist.
At line:13 char:25
+     foreach ($group in (Get-Acl $_).Access.IdentityReference)

Comment: I am going to continue to work on the script today in the attempt to figure out why Get-ACL is unable to get the full path of the folders from the previous GCI command. Due to my limited PS knowledge I can't see it initially but will try and figure it out, and I will update my response when I have.

Comment: By the way generally your response is quite right and have interpreted what I am trying to achieve, it has been very helpful, especially in using the foreach-object command, which I think now looking at what you have provided could have been what I was missing.

Comment: Oops. Did you get it working? Try `(Get-Acl $_.FullName)` in that place ti reference the full path to it. As from your other question, it looks like what you want is reasonably straight forward, but not trivial - it will probably take some understanding of collections and objects / pipeline work to do it neatly. And this FolderMap approach is the hashtable approach I was trying to answer in the other question, which maps folder paths to the person - and probably needs `$FolderMap[$_.FullName] = $CsvRow` as well, for the same reason Get-ACL does. (Edited both into my answer here).